# javascript onclick order of events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button to perform a calculation and an indicator:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="$('#busy').show(); calculate();">Ok</button>
<div id="busy" style="display: none;">Calculating...</div>
```

What the browser does in this case is calculate(), and then show the div
Same problem when the calculate() function first tries to show the div and then calculates.

How do I make the events happen in the intended order?

EDIT: 
Maybe the css does change before the calculation, but it is not rendered until after the calculation. 
Also tried with click event handling but same thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7rAJ/

Comment: You should describe your problem a little better.

Comment: browser doesn't have enough time to redraw the UI maybe. The question could be what make you think calculate() is called before?

Comment: Calculate takes about 10 seconds. It takes 10 seconds for the div to show.

Comment: So, please consider to provide a jsfiddle to reproduce your issue. Or at least, show us code of calculate() function. And is it on all browser or specific to one?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7rAJ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `.show()` does nothing else than performing a change in the `display` css property (alongside some magic on previous states).

However, everything happens in *syncronized* code. Its virtually impossible that your `calculate()` method is called first here.

---

Its much more likely that your `calculate()` method is doing some heavy synronized, blocking operations and that the browser batches the two code segements together. It happens to be that in browsers, Javascript code, CSS Rendering and general "UI repaints and reflows", are processed in the same *queue* and therefore in the same thread. I'm talking about the such called "*UI Queue*" here.

In short words, you need to make your `calculate()` function "faster", decouple it into smaller chunks. The worst option would be to entirely *defer* the calling of `calculate()` by invoking a `setTimeout`. That latter would solve your immediate problem, but it would still block the browser and the UI queue afterwards.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5E2bn/1/

As I already stated, you don't really want to do that, its just an example to make the point clear. In any real-world scenario you should go back to the drawing board and think about what `calculate()` does here and how you can split it up into smaller chunks.

One very convenient way to decouple long-running processes in Javascript is the usage of *Run-away script timers*, which basically chunk a sync loop into multiple asyncronous loops to give the UI queue and the browser time to breath in between code executions.

Comment: @roasted that might well be. But it wouldn't change anything on the *order of code execution*

Comment: Thanks. The timeout works. calculate() can't really be more efficient or be split, it generates public/private key pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like coz setTimeout might not be a good option

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    if (calculate()) {
        $('#busy').show();
    }
});
```

Make sure you return true or false : #busy will be shown only once the value from calculate() function is returned